# Error while export of site in a unattached content database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a content database to a sql server which is used by Sharepoint 2010.

Using central administration, I am able to browse the sites and export the sites.

I worte a program to use the Sharepoint APIs to do the same but I get the following error. I am filling the settings structure and calling export.run.

The url I am sending for the export

//vinay10:2434/sites/99156/test112/111

vinay10:2434 is the central admin webapp.

`SPExportObject exportObject = new SPExportObject();
            exportObject.Id = id;
            exportObject.Type = SPDeploymentObjectType.Web;
            exportObject.IncludeDescendants = SPIncludeDescendants.Content;
settings.UnattachedContentDatabase = contentdatabase;settings.ExportObjects.Add(exportObject);SPExport export = new SPExport(settings);export.Run();`

And using the central admin too it shows similar values --- //vinay10:2434/sites/99156 is the site collection

sites/99156/test112/111 is the site.

I attached the content database also before calling export.run. But I get the following error. Can any one tell me what I am missing?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: sites/99156/temp2/111 at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUnattachedDatabaseUtility.LookupIdContentDatabase(SPContentDatabase
>   database, String serverRelativeUrl) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase,
>   Uri requestUri, Boolean isHostHeader) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.InitializeExport()

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the url to the site is server relative? Mostly they are site collection relative, ie:

//vinay10:2434/sites/99156 is the site collection

test112/111 is the site. Use this url if you can.

Comment: While setting the settings of the export function before calling export.run() . If I try to add the server ralative url it complaints that its not a valid url . I tried that too but the exception comes while setting the url in settings.url                                                Heres the code

Comment: Hi I got the solution , I was setting the weburl in the settings instead of teh sitecollection url.